# Installing an old version of swig-python in Mac Ports?

Tags: python, macos, swig, ports

A tool I use needs an older version of `swig` than the version currently in `MacPorts`.

I was able to install `swig 2.0.8_2` using this guide:
[How to install an older version of a port](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/howto/InstallingOlderPort) 
and it works fine.

However, I need the corresponding `swig-python` package as well. I am unable to to find the older `swig-python` package. Searching on mac ports yields only [this result](http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=library&substr=swig-python), which takes me to the swig repository and doesn't seem to have a port file for the python binding.

**Questions:**

- *How can I find the older version of `swig-python` I need?*
- *Is it somehow part of the swig repo?*

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. port install subport=swig-python in the same directory as swig's portfile.